# Writing an IO String to stdout in Haskell

Tags: haskell, io, stdout

How do we print the output of a function that returns an IO String to the stdout? I am not able to use show or print.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you want to print the result of the function `foo :: Int -> IO String` (for example), you can do

```
main = do
    str <- foo 12
    putStrLn str
```

or, without the do-notation,

```
main = foo 12 >>= putStrLn.
```

The do-notation is syntactic sugar for the second, which uses the fundamental `(>>=)` combinator, which has the type

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

`IO` is an instance of the `Monad` class, so you can use it here.

```
foo :: Int -> IO String
foo 12 :: IO String

putStrLn :: String -> IO ()

(foo 12) >>= putStrLn :: IO ()
```

Comment: Generally, you could say ´printio = do oi <- io \n print io´

Answer (score 6):

> How do we print the output of a function that returns an IO String to the stdout?

Well let's see. Here's a function that returns an IO String:

```
dumbFunction :: a -> IO String
dumbFunction x = getLine
```

`dumbFunction` is a dumb function (but a function nonetheless!). It ignores its input, and then returns `getLine`, which has the type `IO String`.

So you tell me, how do you print `getLine :: IO String`? The answer is, you don't! This is what we call an "IO action". Note that an IO action is *not* a function, because it does *not* take input. (However, IO actions might acquire input from, well, IO operations such as reading stdin, as `getLine` does. But it is not considered a "function" because it does not accept any traditional input)

So instead of printing out the action itself, you probably want to *run* the action, and then print the result. This can be done as Daniel Fischer described (with `<-`, which can be thought of as the "run" operator).